# transact-sql newbie-error- trying to bulk insert data from multiple files into sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to insert data from multiple files into SQL Server. This is the code I am using--

```
DECLARE @MyCounter int;
DECLARE @Fileprefix nvarchar, @Filesuffix nvarchar, @fullname nvarchar, @Counter_string nvarchar;

SET @MyCounter = 1;
SET @Fileprefix= 'C:\Arvind_gpd\patents\';
SET @Filesuffix='data_corrected.csv';

WHILE (@MyCounter < 10)

BEGIN;
Set @Counter_string= Cast(@MyCounter AS varchar(1) );
Set @fullname = (@Fileprefix+ @Counter_string + @Filesuffix );
BULK INSERT GooglePatentsIndividualDec2012.dbo.patent
FROM  @fullname WITH  ( DATAFILETYPE = 'char', FIELDTERMINATOR = '^', ROWTERMINATOR =     '\n' );
SET @MyCounter = @MyCounter + 1;
END;  
GO
```

However I am getting these error messages--

```
  Incorrect syntax near @fullname. Expecting Integer, String, TEXT_LEX.....
  Incorrect syntax near DATAFILETYPE. Expecting SELECT or '('
```

What am I doing wrong in the above query?

Comment: Why the `;` after `set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a variable as a table name. If you want to use a variable you have to create a string and use the `EXEC` function like this:

```
DECLARE @fullname nvarchar, @sql nvarchar
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @fullname+ ' WHERE id = 1'
EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a variable as a filename. According to the syntax described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188365.aspx) it has to be a constant.

You may create the command and use EXEC to execute it.

```
set @Command = 'BULK INSERT GooglePatentsIndividualDec2012.dbo.patent '
set @Command = @Command + 'FROM  '''+@fullname+''' WITH  ( '
set @Command = @Command + 'DATAFILETYPE = ''char'', '
set @Command = @Command ü 'FIELDTERMINATOR = ''^'', ROWTERMINATOR =     ''\n'' )'

EXEC (@Command)
```